# Why isn't my config object available in my other rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

My file layout is like:

```
RakeFile
Tasks/*.rake
```

In my main RakeFile I have:

```
config = # load from yaml
```

Now in my other rake files (in the tasks folder), if I make reference to config it says the method or variable doesn't exist.

Why isn't it reachable in my *.rake files?  How can I fix this?

BTW, where are the built-in rails rake files, I want to see how they created their rake tasks for running migrations, dropping the db, seeding etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails project, your custom tasks should be in the `lib/tasks` directory to get pulled in automatically.

The built-in tasks can be found in [`railties/lib/rails/tasks`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks) for a number of them, and some others are spread out in places like [`activerecord/lib/active_record/railties`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake). You'll have to look around to find them all, or perhaps use the `find` command.

Comment: Why did you tag it with ruby-on-rails?